# Is this allowed to bribe when I am forced?

Tags: halal-haram

I am trying to accomplish a task for me. A person is assigned to verify me but unfortunately s/he is asking to give them some cost (to be clear, bribe).

**Is this kind of bribe allowed for the one who giving** (which is me in the current scenario)?

Points to be noted:

- I am not competing anyone. No one will be harmed directly by this bribe (but of course, there is social impact of bribe).
- I am not trying to do anything illegal.
- I am being forced to bribe and have no other option.

Comment: Being forced to bride is called blackmail or extortion.  You are a victim, not a sinner or going against a hadith.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it permissible in Islam to bribe someone out of compulsion?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/is-it-permissible-in-islam-to-bribe-someone-out-of-compulsion)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Narrated by Ahmad (10739) from ‘Umar ibn al-Khattaab, according to
>   which the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon
>   him) said: “One of them asks me for something and I give it to him,
>   and he goes out with it, carrying it under his arm, and it is nothing
>   but fire for him.” ‘Umar said: O Messenger of Allaah, why do you give
>   it to them?” He said: “They insist on asking me, and Allaah insists
>   that I should not be stingy.” Classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in
>   Saheeh al-Targheeb, 844.

This is the hadith which scholars say means that if someone is forced to pay a bribe, it's ok and the one who takes it will be sinning.

[Source](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/72268).

If you read the [source](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/72268), they mention that if you can get the job done without paying the bribe, but still pay the bribe, both the giver and receiver would be sinning.

Comment: I will check the source when I am free and consider accepting the answer. +1 For now.