# Bribery in Islam under certain conditions

Tags: sharia, practical-islam

I know that bribery is Haram in Islam. But I want to know if it's permissible under certain circumstances. For example, when bidding for projects, if you don't pay some amount of money to the guy who gives you the contract, you wont be able to get the project, no matter how qualified you are for the job. Anyone who gives him money(which is a bribe) will get the contract. Now if you **think** that you are qualified for the job and you are sure that you can accomplish all the tasks, **is it permissible to give a bribe in this case?**

Comment: Similar: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/is-allowed-in-islam-to-bribe-out-of-compulsion-or-to-under-value-the-item-becaus/1617#1617